# Absolutely positioned element inside container with overflow: auto

Tags: css

We have a modal with `position: fixed` and `overflow-y: auto`.

This works well when we have lots of components that overflow since then the scroll bar is shown.

However when we have a custom calendar field inside the modal which opens a popup/dropdown calendar and that element is outside one of the sides of the container, it's not shown.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to make the popup/dropdown shown while keeping the `overflow-y: auto` of the modal? Like so:

[image: screenshot2]

Codepen to elaborate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWmNMa

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 30%;

  /* comment out this to show dropdown*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="dropdown">
    This is content in a dropdown.
  </div>
  Long long overflowing text...
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, it's not possible for an **absolutely** positioned child element to appear outside of the parent `.modal` element when it has `overflow: auto` set on it (unless you set the `position` of the `.dropdown` element to `fixed`).

The easiest work-around would be to wrap the text and other contents, and then set `overflow: auto` on that element. For instance, you could wrap it with a `.content` element, and then set `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` in order to add a scrollbar and hide the overflow for those specific elements.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wrjedd)

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="dropdown">
    This is content in a dropdown.
  </div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 30%;
}
.modal .content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrVbQR) worked for me.

Of course, you're limited by the inconvenient effect of `position:fixed;` but this **does** achieve your desired result.

```
.dropdown {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Hope that helps.